# Pulseaudio doesn't react to changes in daemon.conf, and pulseaudio --dump-conf always shows the same output

Tags: pulseaudio, strace

I was trying to lower the audio sample rate for a test, but I noted that nothing was changing the sound quality.

I tried changing sample rate in /etc/pulse/daemon.conf, the single daemon.conf file in my OS (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS), but nothing changed.

More than that, pulseaudio --dump-conf still showed the same old values, even though it said it was read from that exact path. I rebooted and it didn't change either.

Then I tested just renaming that file. Now it no longer said it read from there, but still dumped the same data.

I ran an strace to see all files it accessed. The only file that it still found was "default.pa", I renamed it too, and guess what? It STILL outputs the same.

Is this hardcoded in the binary?

Because literally every single file it tries to access, according to strace, has been renamed by me, so all of them now return "file not found" when it tries to access and it still prints out the same output in the end.

It can't be getting it from anywhere.

So, what option I have left?

I'm using pulseaudio 11.1

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 has been End of Standard Support since June 2023 and is off topic here. Please upgrade to a supported version of Ubuntu.